# Saving data Django Channels 2

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to save the data which i am receiving from my client using the Django Channels.

I have read the documentation but its not very clear.

Here is my code of consumer.py

```
 def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

        # Receive message from room group

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        message2 = message[1]
        self.save_data(message2)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message2
        }))

    @database_sync_to_async
    def save_data (self, message):
        return DeviceLogs.objects.create(voltage=message)
```

As you may have noticed that i just want to save message2 in database.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the problem in your code but this should work for you.

```
async def chat_message(self, event):
    ...
    message2 = message[1]
    await self.save_message(message2)
    ...

@database_sync_to_async
def save_message(self, message):
        ... save message here
```

Comment: `@database_sync_to_async`  is useful for maintaining connections clean and ensuring that *connection* gets closed after operation

Comment: No data is being saved. Moreover, i am using async_to_sync

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your consumer extends `WebsocketConsumer` (sync consumer). If that is the case, remove the `@database_sync_to_async` decorator and it should be fine. You only need to do that if your consumer is async.

From the docs:

> The Django ORM is a synchronous piece of code, and so if you want to access it from asynchronous code you need to do special handling to make sure its connections are closed properly.
>
> If you’re using `SyncConsumer`, or anything based on it - like `JsonWebsocketConsumer` - you don’t need to do anything special, as all your code is already run in a synchronous mode and Channels will do the cleanup for you as part of the `SyncConsumer` code.
>
> If you are writing asynchronous code, however, you will need to call database methods in a safe, synchronous context, using `database_sync_to_async`.

Comment: Hey, can I get some help? I managed to save the data and I am using the same consumer as the OP. How can I preload the last 10 sent messages when I load the chatroom?